# Image not getting rendered in react application

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-image

Unable to render images in react, In browser console, image names are displayed correctly but on UI it is not displayed. Also, src attribute is missing from `img` tag after inspecting element. Please assist. [Here is Sample Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7BEw.png)

```
function importAll(r) {
    let images = {};
    r.keys().map((item, index) => { images[item.replace('./', '')] = r(item); });
    return images;
}

const get_images = importAll(require.context('../../images', true, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));

const images = Object.entries(get_images).map(module => module[1].default);

return (
    <div className="product">
        <div>
            <Row>
                {products.map(product =>
                    <Col span={6} key={product.productId}>
                        <div >
                            
                            <div>{console.log(product.productImageName)}
                                {<Image src={images[product.productImageName]} width={200} 
height={200} />}
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                )
                }
            </Row>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Why `<Image>` is inside `{}`?

Comment: yes that is not required , removed it

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to import images. if images are part of your repository then you can use the `relative` path from the `src` directory. e.g assuming the `images` in under `src`

```
const path = `images/${[product.productImageName]}`;
<Image src={path} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try and check if profile exist. Like this:

```
{profile && profile.map((...

//Or

{profile?.map((...
```

Comment: Its working now, got a video where it was suggested to put all images inside public folder so that it can be searched by webpack, thanks anyway.